# I want to print all uppercase letters to lowercase letter in assembly language

Tags: assembly

My input is
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

output is:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

How can I do this??Can anyone help me.I am new in assembly language.

here I can try this one,

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.code
.data

    msg1 db 'Enter a Uppercase letter: $'

    msg2 db 0DH, 0AH, 'Lowercase letter is :'

    char db ?, '$'

main proc

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    lea dx, msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov cx,26

    mov ah,1
    int 21h

    add al,20h
    mov char,al

    lea dx, msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h


MOV AH,4CH
int 21h

main endp

end main
```

But this one print only single character.If I input: A then output : a

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this...

Where you have `char db ?, '$'`, instead:

```
char db 81 dup(?)  # make space for up to 80 chars plus a `$` terminator
```

Then from your `mov cx, 26`, instead:

```
    lea cx, char # cx holds current position in output string

readone:
    mov ah, 1    # existing code to get a char
    int 21h      # existing code to get a char
    cmp al, 10   # is the char a newline?
    je printstr  # if it is, no need to go further
    add al, 20h  # existing code to convert case (if not newline)
    mov [cx],al  # move the converted character to the current string position 
                 # literally: move the value in al to the address in cx
    inc cx       # move to next position in string
    jmp readone  # read another char

printstr:
    mov [cx], 36 # add the trailing $ to the output string
    lea dx, msg2 # existing code
    mov ah, 9    # existing code
    int 21       # existing code        
    ...          # the rest of your code
```

Something like this should take input until you press the Enter key, then print the converted string (I can't check because I am not running your system or assembler).

It does no error checking (your input had better be all upper case chars, or the output will be unpredictable!).